# Unwanted horizontal scroll bar in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css

I have a site that is working fine, **except in IE7** there is a massive horizontal scroll bar.

I would have to paste the entire html code and css code so I will refer you to the page source.

You can see the site [here](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/first_trust/index.html).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I just had the same problem however I had a div that was `98% width` and `1% padding` on each side, to fix the problem I had to change the div's `width to 97.9%`... weird I know but it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a strange challenge as there was nothing that appeared to be causing the issue. However, thanks to [Tony Crockford](http://boldfish.co.uk) he noted that there was a div with italic text in it that might be causing the issue. And sure enough it was.

Here it the suspect code:

```
<span class="strength">strength...experience...understanding</span>
```

I had that styled to be italic:

```
span.strength { 
 float: right; 
 margin: -60px 0 0 0; 
 font: italic 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
 color: #16506a; 
 }
```

However there is a bug that causes problems: http://www.brunildo.org/test/ie7_ithscroll.html

And this is the solution:

```
 overflow: auto;
```

Crazy stuff! But it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a horizontal scrollbar (FF 3.6.3 Ubuntu 10.04 1920x1200 res). What resolution are you running at?

You can use `overflow: hidden` to hide the scrollbar.

Comment: Did you try using `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Hi Vivin, I got some more information about this. It was the italic text at the top that was causing the problem:

http://www.brunildo.org/test/ie7_ithscroll.html

Comment: Wow, had no idea! What a strange bug! You might want to post your own answer to this question and then accept it when you are able to (usually after 2 days).